# 365 E3 SharePoint (Plan 2) Account --- Record Center sub-site --PLEASE HELP!

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sub-site, records-center

I am trying to create a Record Center sub-site for our compliance team. The Document Center sub-site was created no problem. But now when I try to create the Record Center from the template it goes as far as saying "Working on it" and then I hit a request access page. I did the request action but my admin says they never got a request. Is there some limitation or feature that must be turned on first at the top level site for this to work? Is this a Bug? Is it even possible to get the Record Center Template to work at the sub-site level. Any help or insight is really appreciated. I already convinced my whole team this was the product to use to build our solution and I was sure this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may be concerned and having the same problem. The solution was that our IT rep as the Site Collection Admin needed to create the Records Center herself even thought my "rights" were set as an owner for the top level site with "create subsites" checked. Things seem to be working now.